# Provide Services to many Lightweigh Nodes (SPVs) and Save The Communication History

Tags: full-node, spv, bip37-bloom-filter, logging

I am investigating on privacy violations of the current communication protocol between lightweight clients and full nodes in the Bitcoin network, which utilizes Bloom filters. I run a full node on my Machine.

First, I want to make sure that a sufficient number of lightweight wallets are connected to the node. Second I want to save the communication history of each session between the full node and an SPV node. Specifically, filterload, filteradd, transactions, merkleblock, etc. (According to bip-0037)

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> First, I want to make sure that a sufficient number of lightweight wallets are connected to the node.

There's very little use of BIP37 today, and it's not even served by default by modern versions of Bitcoin Core. The chance that anybody would even connect to you and supply filters to you is extremely low. It was always a terrible idea to begin with, giving poor performance for users, poor privacy, and exposing the software to a denial of service hole the size of Norway.

> Second I want to save the communication history of each session between the full node and an SPV node. Specifically, filterload, filteradd, transactions, merkleblock, etc. (According to bip-0037)

This is trivial with basic development skills, if a little frowned upon. The software naturally doesn't support anything of the sort out of the box, even when bloom filters are manually enabled in the configuration.